# How to do initialization of properties of a complex Object Model based on given type of theme?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have complex object model(involving lot of inheritance/composition). some of its properties qualify as part of a theme.
Given a theme i want to initialize its various properties.

How shall i design a Generic Theme class?

Is there any design pattern to support this ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. We don't even know what you mean by "theme". But you could have a populate(ComplexObjectModel model) in your Theme class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme to me sounds like a collection of visual properties, like font size, background colors, etc. Your complex object model almost sounds like a controls/UI element hierarchy where each control/element has properties that you want the Theme class to initialize.

What you would need to do is for each object in your complex object model to be themeable, so we create IThemeable:

```
interface IThemeable
{
     void UpdateThemeableProperties();
}
```

To make more sense out of UpdateThemeableProperties(), let's implement it in one of your complex objects.

```
class AComplexObject implements IThemable
{
     public bool Selected; // a primitive property we want themeble

     public AnotherComplexObject anotherComplexObject; // implements IThemeable

     public List<IThemable> Children;

     // your object may have other themeable and non-themeable properties.

     public AComplexObject()
     {
         Children = new List<IThemable>();
         UpdateThemableProperties();
     }

     public void UpdateThemableProperties()
     {        
         if (App.CurrentTheme != null)
         {
             // take care of your primitive properties first by practice
             object valueFromTheme = App.CurrentTheme.getPropertyValue("AComplexObject,"Selected");
             Selected = (valueFromTheme != null) ? valueFromTheme : false;
             // false would be the default value if the theme didn't provide it.

             // Do the same as above for all primitive properties you want to
             // participate in the theme.

             // Do for each individual complex property
             if(anotherComplexObject != null)
             {
                anotherComplexObject.UpdateThemeableProperties();
             }

             // Do for each of your lists of complex objects:
             for each (IThemable it in Children)
             {
                  it.UpdateThemeableProperties();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

App would be a global static class, and CurrentTheme would be one of its member. We create the function UpdateThemeableProperties() because it is called many times, even within one class.

Inside UpdateThemeableProperties, we seek out the current theme's values for the implementing class and property combination with the function CurrentTheme.getPropertyValue(className,propertyName) where className and propertyName are both strings. (Yes, we hard-code the class name and property name). The function returns an Object type although the actual type matches the type of the property you're setting. Also, remember to provide a default value in case CurrentTheme didn't specify one.

Notice that each complex property of anything in your complex object model is an IThemable. That's why we can call UpdateThemeableProperties() on all of them, even those that are on a List structure.

Now, the CurrentTheme:

```
class CurrentTheme
{
    private Dictionary<String,Object> values;

    public CurrentTheme()
    {
         values = new Dictionary<String,Object>();
    }

    public void setPropertyValue(string className, string propertyName, Object value)
    {
         values.add(className + "_" + propertyName, value);
    }

    public Object getPropertyValue(string className, string propertyName)
    {
         if (values.keyExists(className + "_" + propertyName)
         {
             return values[className + "_" + propertyName];
         }
         else
         {
             return null;
         }
    }

}
```

Note that your language's implementation of Dictionary might be different. Take the above code as somewhat of a pseudocode.

In your initialization stage, you might want to set the theme. In a later stage, you typically build/instantiate your complex model. Instantiation of your complex model may have found its value from the current theme, but after instantiation, call YourRootMostComplexObject.UpdateThemeableProperties() to refresh and ensure that all children will get their properties from the current theme.

When you change themes (by the selection of another one from a drop down list, for example), you will need to call YourRootMostComplexObject.UpdateThemeableProperties() again to update everything.

When adding a child (like adding an item to List) at runtime, call child.UpdateThemeableProperties():

```
public addChild(SomeComplexObjectThatImplementsIThemeable child)
{
     Children.add(child);
     child.UpdateThemeableProperties();
}
```

That was quite a long post. In summary,

- Each class in your complex object model that have themeable
  properties MUST implement IThemeable.
- Remember to implement every IThemeable class's UpdateThemeableProperties(). You will need to know which properties are themeable before you try to obtain its value from the current theme.
- UpdateThemeableProperties() is called in an IThemeable class's constructor, after the current theme is changed, when adding an IThemeable item on a list, and when instantiating a property of a type that implements IThemeable.